# Asynchronous update of a ListActivity

Tags: android, xml, asynchronous, listactivity

May I update a ListActivity after loading Content from an external XML ressource :/?

`SUB()` is ListActivity

```
Main() -> opening: SUB() -> updating from xml -> getting result -> updating SUB()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [AsyncTask<>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: So it is possible to use async task and update the listview while it is displayed?

Comment: Yes it is... if you have specific issues, ask a new question with details.